# Reversing doubly-link list using iterator

Tags: java, iterator, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create a method which reverses the elements of a doubly-linked list. The class has a dummy node in which dummy.next would equal the head and dummy.prev would equal the tail. I have an iterator

```
 public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int i) {
if (i < 0 || i > n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
return new Iterator(this, i);
}
```

My reverse code is as follows

```
  public void reverse() {
ListIterator<T> it = listIterator(0);
Node temp = dummy.next;
dummy.next = dummy.prev;
dummy.prev = temp;

Node p = dummy.next;

while(it.hasNext())
{
  temp=p.next;
  p.next=p.prev;
  p.prev=temp;
  p=p.next;
}
}
```

When given an empty DList, it passes just fine, but once it is given one that has element, it loops infinitely. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong so any help would be nice.

Comment: You never use the values generated by the iterator, thus `it.hasNext()` always evaluates to the same value (`true` in your case).

Comment: aka you need to call `it.next()` to actually advance the iterator.